# Error message - Element not interactable Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, element

[image]I have created the following code which is meant to pull data from the webiste and convert to excel.

I have no problems getting the data into excel, however there are a number of accordion toggles hidding some of the data which i have tried to toggle open.

However i get a 'element not interactive' error. i have seen a number of similar issues with this error, and i cant pinpoint why this isnt working?

(the accordion toggle works fine- but then it says not visible?)

Australian Website btw.

see below full code and error further below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


chrome_path =r"C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"

d = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
d.get("https://pointsbet.com.au/basketball/NCAA-March-Madness")

time.sleep(2)

d.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/sport-competition-component/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/event-list/div[1]/event/div/header/div[1]/h2/a""").click()
time.sleep(2)

expandable = WebDriverWait(d, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".h2.accordion-toggle.event-name")))
expandables = d.find_elements_by_css_selector('.h2.accordion-toggle.event-name')
for item in expandables:
    item.click()


posts = d.find_elements_by_class_name("market")
for post in posts:
    print(post.text)
    with open('output.xls',mode ='a') as f:
        f.write(post.text)
        f.write('\n')

d.quit()
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Python test\points1 - Copy.py", line 21, in <module>
    item.click()
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: at which element you are getting this exception

Comment: Full error is now in the orignal post (Click Element)

Comment: you tell us that at what line you are getting , how do we supposed to know??

Comment: sorry im new to coding. Im pretty sure its line 21

Comment: can you share the screen shot of the web screen which element you are trying to find with the devtools

Comment: screen shot attached

Comment: can you used chropath which is an element selector finder tool you will find it here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chropath/ljngjbnaijcbncmcnjfhigebomdlkcjo?hl=en

Comment: and try to find the different selector like xpath and all

Comment: what is the code for xpath selector? is it 'EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.xpath_SELECTOR'?

Comment: have you add the extention chropath in the browser

Comment: https://browsee.io/blog/chropath-a-quick-way-to-get-and-verify-xpath-and-css-selectors/ look

Comment: Answers to the "duplicate" questions don't solve my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Action` class to click the element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

d.get("https://pointsbet.com.au/basketball/NCAA-March-Madness")

WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//h2/a[@class="ng-binding"]'))).click()


expandable = WebDriverWait(d, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".h2.accordion-toggle.event-name")))
expandables = d.find_elements_by_css_selector('.h2.accordion-toggle.event-name')
for item in expandables:
  ActionChains(d).move_to_element(item).click().perform() # item.click()



posts = d.find_elements_by_class_name("market")
for post in posts:
    print(post.text)


d.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks Kajal, That worked perfectly. as a side question is there a way to repeat the code on a loop and pick up the second match under WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//h2/a[@class="ng-binding"]'))).click()
As This would help me collect data for multiple matches at any one time.

Comment: I have to check that mate.currently away from work.